# Uploading/Downloading Files in Banno Mobile Webview

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We currently set up a chat plugin in the Banno mobile app. Upon clicking a button, we open a full screen webview to our authenticated chat on a separate website that runs in the Banno app. In the Android Banno app, we are unable to upload or open files in this chat. In the iPhone app, I can upload files but cannot open files without copying the file link.  In the Chrome browser on both devices, file uploading and downloading works fine. Are there any Banno app permissions preventing us from uploading/downloading files in the full screen web view?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably running into [Restrictions for the Plugin Framework](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) around *"Sandboxing"* and/or perhaps *"Rendering PDFS"*.

- Also, the Banno Mobile native apps use webviews which are based on standard HTML, CSS and JavaScript, but the full complexity of a modern browser is not supported. Which means even if things aren't specifically *restricted* they may not be specifically *supported*.

You may want to consider using the [Plugin Bridge to activate the Expanded View](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/#activating-the-expanded-view-from-the-card-face) from the Card Face and given the limitations of the mobile webviews you may want to use its ability to [bounce users over to an actual web browser](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/).

Comment: Thank you Jaime for your response. We considered integrating a mobile browser-based approach using the bridge. However, our primary concern revolves around the inconvenience users might face, specifically the need to repeatedly enter a PIN each time they toggle back to the Banno app. Ideally, we are aiming for a more seamless experience where users aren't required to switch back to the app. Instead, we prefer a redirection. Could you advise if there's a feasible solution to implement this functionality?

Comment: I hope that you had a nice New Years.  I am following up on this thread. Thank you.

Comment: There isn't any alternative to what I've already described.